# How to access a function of a child component in a unit test

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme

Consider a simple React component:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    testMethod(): boolean {
        console.log('called testMethod!');
        return true;
    } 

    render() {
      return <div>Hello, World!</div>
    }
}

export default withParent(Child);
```

`withParent` for the sake of simplicity in this example is  a simple HOC that just returns the child component:

```
const withParent = (WrappedComponent): ComponentClass => {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent { ...this.props } />;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, assume I have a simple enzyme test for `Child`. I'd like to be able to unit test the individual methods of `Child`, in this case the method `testMethod`:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {
    configure,
    shallow
} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Child from './Child';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('ChildTests', () => {

    it('can handle calling testMethod', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Child />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        // how would I do something like wrapper.testMethod() here?
        const result = instance.testMethod();
        expect(result).toEqual(true);
    });
}
```

Is it possible to access and unit test individual class methods of the `Child` component when it is wrapped by an HOC? I am able to access and call `testMethod` if `Child` is **not** wrapped by an HOC.

Answer (score 0):

`const instance = wrapper.dive().dive().dive().dive().instance();`

I had to dive down the number of HOCs that are wrapping the component.

Comment: another option(better one, I believe) is export _unwrapped_ component as well.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly export your `child` component and then import it using named import in your test.

Here is how:

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
    testMethod(): boolean {
        console.log('called testMethod!');
        return true;
    } 

    render() {
      return <div>Hello, World!</div>
    }
}

export default withParent(Child);
```

So we have 2 exports from here. Let the HOC(child) be the default component.

Now in the test use `import { Child } from './Child';`

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {
    configure,
    shallow
} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Child } from './Child';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('ChildTests', () => {

    it('can handle calling testMethod', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Child />);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        const result = instance.testMethod();
        expect(result).toEqual(true);
    });
}
```